# phonegap build command resetting the asset/www source code

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ant, build

Whenever I execute phonegap build android/ios, my asset folder is getting reset to sample folder and source code.

Because of this , whatever  the code I am copying into the asset/www it is being overwritten by sample codes of phonegap

Does anybody come across this issue.
What could be the reason.?

Comment: why -1 , What is the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behavior of cordova/phonegap project.

Under **yourProjectRoot/platforms/android/assets/www** there are the source copied in build phase from the **yourProjectRoot/www** directory, you must implement your HTML5/js code in this folder, this is the entry point for you source.

I suggest you to take a look here: [Build the App](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) before start the development.

Comment: @PavanKumar: I think you are building your app from platforms/android/assets/www  Which is wrong. You must start building your app from RootProject/www folder.

Answer (score 0):

Help of PhoneGap build command says:

> Builds your application for one or more specified platforms. When no
>     platforms are specified, all installed platforms will be built.
>
> The build task will first prepare and then compile your application.
>     If you want more control, you can individually prepare and compile
>     your application with the commands.

Your platform specific www folder is overwritten because `prepare` command is fired.

If you preparing your entire project in platform specific folder like `${PROJECT_ROOT}/platforms/android` and you want to compile it than you have to run `phonegap compile your_platform`. It will bypass `prepare` and go straight to `compile`.